# Getting all file names from a folder using C#

Tags: c#, list, text-files, directory

I wanted to know if it is possible to get all the names of text files in a certain folder.

For example, I have a folder with the name Maps, and I would like to get the names of all the text files in that folder and add it to a list of strings.

Is it possible, and if so, how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 484):

```
using System.IO;

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test"); //Assuming Test is your Folder

FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files
string str = "";

foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  str = str + ", " + file.Name;
}
```

Comment: Using System.IO;

Comment: FileInfo has a lot of overhead, it would be much better to use Path.GetFileName(filePath)

Comment: How does `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` compare to the `Directory.GetFiles` approach?

Comment: @Jeff Please be under some answers, where it's not obvious which namespaces are used :D Thx.

Answer (score 212):

```
using System.IO; //add this namespace also
```

---

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Maps\", "*.txt",
                                         SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Comment: How does `Directory.GetFiles` compare to the `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` approach?

Comment: @AaronFranke `Directory.GetFiles` will give you an array of fullpaths of the files contained in the Directory, whereas the `DirectoryInfo` approach will give you an array of `FileInfo`, which contains more info about each file, such as filename, extension, size, modified time, etc.

Answer (score 90):

It depends on what you want to do.

ref: http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/

This will bring back ALL the files in the specified directory

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Dir\");
```

This will bring back ALL the files in the specified directory with a certain extension

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Dir\", "*.jpg");
```

This will bring back ALL the files in the specified directory AS WELL AS all subdirectories with a certain extension

```
string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Dir\", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 18):

Does exactly what you want.

[System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx)

Comment: `IO` is capitalized.

Comment: Around here we discourage simply linking to the manual. Next time you should also paste in the relevant information with your answer here.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at *[Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx)* (MSDN).

This method returns all the files as an array of filenames.

Answer (score 8):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx

The System.IO namespace has loads of methods to help you with file operations.  The

```
Directory.GetFiles()
```

method returns an array of strings which represent the files in the target directory.

Answer (score -11):

I would recommend you google 'Read objects in folder'. You might need to create a reader and a list and let the reader read all the object names in the folder and add them to the list in n loops.

Comment: Much more efficient to use the inbuilt GetFiles method on the Directory class.