# C# List Contents of Given Directory

Tags: c#, console, directory

How do I list the contents of a given directory?

We can say `private string directory = @"C:\";` and what I then want is to use `Console.WriteLine()` to display the contents of `directory`.

However, after hours of research on this site, I still could not find an answer that worked. I have tried solutions like `Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))` but the code failed to build. **How do I fix this?**

I have this at the beginning of my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
```

Am I missing something? What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all file names from a folder using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877237/getting-all-file-names-from-a-folder-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @AlexK.  I think this is more of a case of finding the correct using statement rather than enumerating file names

Comment: Show us the whole code that failed to build. We can then help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Directory.EnumerateDirectories()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383304(v=vs.110).aspx) returns an enumeration of all subdirectories of the specified directory.

```
foreach (var dir in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"C:\"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dir);
}
```

If however or in addition you wish to specify all files, use [File.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Both of these are in the System.IO namespace, so include this in your using section

```
using System.IO;
```

Comment: Now Visual Studio says that GetFiles isn't defined by System.IO

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
```

Visual Studio offers a nice feature for the situations where you don't know which `using` statement you need:  Right click on `Directory` and the second option (in VS 2013) is "Resolve", then a sub-menu with "using System.IO".  Click that sub-menu item and it will automatically add the `using` statement.