# Add fonts by CMD and C#

Tags: c#, cmd, fonts, registry

I write a method to install fonts by cmd and C#.
My method as below :

```
void installFont(string fontsFolderPath, string fontName)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        String cc = @"/C  copy " + fontsFolderPath + @" C:\Windows\Fonts" + "&REG ADD HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows_NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts /v " + fontName + @"  /t REG_SZ /d   " + fontName + @".ttf /f &pause"; ;
        startInfo.Arguments = cc;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();   
    }
```

but that is not add it, I try the cmd instructions individually, it's work correctly but when I request them by  C# they are not working.
I run VS as administrator.
What the error in my code, or what the better way to do this Job.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This could be a big maybe but you have "C:\windows\Fonts" + "&REG" there is no space between your fonts path and your registry command.  Its possible CMD is interpreting that as one continuous path.  Also I am not sure you can run all those as 1 argument you might have to redirect the input and write the commands individually. here is a link on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437419/execute-multiple-command-lines-with-the-same-process-using-net

Comment: I add space but it's not working.

Comment: then its likely that copy is interpreting your reg commands as switches for it and not understanding what to do.  Have a look at the link I posted and specifically the one that shows how to redirect the input so that you can run multiple commands like they are new commands to that same process.

Comment: Can you show exactly what the cc string is when you start the process.

Comment: @PaulF
that is cc:
/C  copy C:\Folder\ C:\Windows\Fonts &REG ADD HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows_NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts /v Libertinage  /t REG_SZ /d   Libertinage.ttf /f &pause

Comment: why you dont use simple copy and then add to registry..i test this way and it work fine..if you want i can put some code to your hint

Comment: @combo_ci can you do that please?

Comment: @PaulF What can I do to run the cmd?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong - see the last comment in the answer below about running as administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [this question and answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f3fcf96f-b508-4a56-a280-ddbb8ca8e2ff/installing-fonts-programatically-c?forum=csharpgeneral) in Microsoft site you can do that by copying te font file in Font folder and add that to registry as blow:

```
File.Copy("BKoodakO.ttf", Path.Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Windows), "Fonts", "BKoodakO.ttf"),true);
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts");
key.SetValue("describtion for BKoodakO", "BKoodakO.ttf");
key.Close();
```

This code copy one file and if you have more file in a folder [Get the font file in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877237/getting-all-file-names-from-a-folder-using-c-sharp) and then copy one by one. I test this way and it work fine. if you have question please comment answer. Note that the output must *Run as administrator*.

Another way that use Windows dll to do that is:

```
        [DllImport("gdi32", EntryPoint = "AddFontResource")]
        public static extern int AddFontResourceA(string lpFileName);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern int AddFontResource(string lpszFilename);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        private static extern int CreateScalableFontResource(uint fdwHidden, string
        lpszFontRes, string lpszFontFile, string lpszCurrentPath);

        /// <summary>
        /// Installs font on the user's system and adds it to the registry so it's available on the next session
        /// Your font must be included in your project with its build path set to 'Content' and its Copy property
        /// set to 'Copy Always'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="contentFontName">Your font to be passed as a resource (i.e. "myfont.tff")</param>
        private static void RegisterFont(string contentFontName)
        {
            // Creates the full path where your font will be installed
            var fontDestination = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath
                                              (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), contentFontName);

            if (!File.Exists(fontDestination))
            {
                // Copies font to destination
                System.IO.File.Copy(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), contentFontName), fontDestination);

                // Retrieves font name
                // Makes sure you reference System.Drawing
                PrivateFontCollection fontCol = new PrivateFontCollection();
                fontCol.AddFontFile(fontDestination);
                var actualFontName = fontCol.Families[0].Name;

                //Add font
                AddFontResource(fontDestination);
                //Add registry entry  
                Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts",
                actualFontName, contentFontName, RegistryValueKind.String);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I try the first method, it's work, but :
1-when the folder is in c directory it can't copy it.
2- If I not run the program as administrator it's also not work.
Many Thanks.

Comment: if you run visual studio as administrator, you not need to run it as administrator, do you try it?

Comment: I not need when I release my project to force user to run it as administrator, How can I do that.
And about folder in c, there is no error but when I check to font existence, it's not exist; i.e. it's cant copy font from folder c.

Comment: about Run as administrator please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Comment: Ali, When a code work, if you have a special case that it not work, you must looking for the reason of that case in your computer, maybe a special permition on your C:/ dive, or some software pervent to do that, if you put in a folder in c:/ , the program is work fine?