# How the edit a specified file (kinda text) with setting only the end of the file name

Tags: c#, text

My code looks like this:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
text = text.Replace("some text", "new value");
File.WriteAllText("test.txt", text);
```

I want to edit two words, not only one:

- From `SIDE` to `*SIDE`
- And `BARCODE` to `*BARCODE`

Also is there any solution to find the file by the end of its name instead of full name? Because the file name is always different but it always ends with a string like `"_ABC.desc"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find file by the end of it's name

```
       string partialName = "text";  // ending part of file name
       DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\");
       FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + ".*");    
       // All files matched that name will show in filesInDir
       foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
       {
           string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
           string text = File.ReadAllText(fullName);// here you will get text 
       }
```

Comment: string text = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");

And with your code what do i have to put instead of "test.txt" ?

Comment: You can use `string text = File.ReadAllText(fullName);` See my updated answer @Tamas555

Answer (score 0):

> i would want to edit two words not only one: -From "SIDE" to "*SIDE"
>   -And "BARCODE" to "*BARCODE"

You can call `Replace()` method again

```
text = text.Replace("some text", "new value").Replace("BARCODE","*BARCODE");
```

> Also is there any solution to find the file by the end of it's name
>   instead of full name?

NO, you will have to specify the actual and full file name along with it's path.
Though you can use `Directory.GetFiles()` to get all file names and probably pass in a RegEx but that's your choice See this post

[Getting all file names from a folder using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877237/getting-all-file-names-from-a-folder-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

To change words you want I would create an array of strings that contains original values and then use regular expression to find out which one to replace.

*Example :*

```
const string PATTERN = @"(?<!\*){0}";
string[] words = new string[] { "SIDE", "BARCODE" };

foreach(string word in words)
{
    Regex r = new Regex(string.Format(PATTERN, word));
    text = r.Replace(text, "*" + word);
}
```

This will ensure that `"*BARCODE"` wont be replaced with `"**BARCODE"` as would do using `String.Replace` method.

You can [try this online](http://rextester.com/SFWWF68357)

---

Second part, to find out files based on the partial input, is well described by [@Manoj answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370687/3179310)