# How to use IronOCR for reading from a directory instead of a single file?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ocr

I am using [IronOCR OCR Library](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/html/N_IronOcr.htm) to read text from a particular area within a PNG image which goes fine. However, I need to do the same with a directory/folder and save it to a directory/folder.

Here's the code that I am currently using

```
public void workOCR()
{
    var ocr = new AutoOcr();
    var Area = new Rectangle()
    {
        X = 1367,
        Y = 420,
        Height = 57,
        Width = 411
    };
    var result = ocr.Read(@"C:\Users\fasihullahkhan\Desktop\pdftopng\page3.png", Area);
    label1.Text = result.Text;
}
```

What I want to do is specify a directory like this:

```
ocr.Read(@"C:\Users\fasihullahkhan\Desktop\pdftopng\", Area);
```

From within a loop, but I don't know how. Please help.

Comment: If you find all `*.png` files of a directory, you can solve the problem. There are a couple of posts about this topic. For example take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877237/getting-all-file-names-from-a-folder-using-c-sharp).

Comment: I have tried that, that's why I have explicitly asked to devise a method that will loop through the directory within the realms of IronOCR. Because the first argument of `ocr.Read()` does not accept an array.

Comment: First of all, it does. Look at [here](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/html/M_IronOcr_AutoOcr_Read_2.htm). Second, if you want to use the overload which accepts filename and rectangle, you can use a for loop and for each element of the array, pass it to `Read` method which accepts filename and the rectangle.

Comment: You also can use this overload [`AdvancedOcr.ReadMultiThreaded`](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/object-reference/html/M_IronOcr_AdvancedOcr_ReadMultiThreaded_4.htm) which accepts a list of files, a rectangle and maximum number of concurrent threads.