# C# WPF style SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, styles, themes

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6792677/5437621) and some other examples to create my custom style. The theme looks fine on the `Window` ( it shows the custom titlebar, background, etc ). But when I open `SaveFileDialog` or any other dialogs, they load the default Windows theme, which make the program look weird ( different styles on different windows ugh... )

I tried implementing my own dialog, but the performance really sucked. I've seen DevExpress and Telerik using custom themes on these dialogs, so I think it's possible.

Is there a way to apply the same style to common dialogs as well?

This is a OpenFileDialog on DevExpress:
[image]

Comment: I don't know abut Telerik but DevExpress did certainly not 'theme' those Dialogs. They created their own implementations. What made performance suck within your dialogs?

Comment: @SanchoPanza I saw many ways to list files/folders, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877330/5437621, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878355/5437621, and many more. but even when there are say 500 files, in directory, it takes time to list them (this is when i'm using my own thumbnails, and not extracting the actual file/folder thumbnails)

Comment: and also its too complex. this is my implementation: http://www.filedropper.com/filepickerdialog